# Proof problem: If $x-1$ is divisible by $4$ then $x^2 - 1$ is divisible by 4

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

The question is to state if it's true or false.

Question: If $x-1$ is divisible by 4 then $x^2 - 1$ is divisible by 4

I'm not very familiar with the mathematical language of elementary number theory compared to calculus, algebra as this is mostly calculations and using the correct properties. It would be great if you can show me steps to understand.

Comment: You already know that $x-1$ is divisible by $4$. Can you express $x^2-1$ as something multiplied by $x-1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x−1$ is divisible by $4$ then $\,x -1 = 4n\,$ for some integer $n\,$. Then $\,x^2-1$ $=(4n+1)^2-1$ $\require{cancel}=16n^2 + 8n + \cancel{1} - \cancel{1} = 8n(2n+1)\,$ is divisible by $8$, which is in turn divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 6):

$x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ this implies the result.

Comment: At least one of them is divisible is by 4 which is x-1, but then x+1 is not?

Comment: @user225875 Let's say $A=x-1$. Therefore, $A/4$ is equal to some integer.

Therefore, $(x+1)*A/4$ is also equal to some integer as $x+1$ evaluates to some integer.

Answer (score 0):

If $4\mid x-1$ then for any polynomial $p(x)$ we have $$4\mid (x-1)\cdot p(x)$$

Specially in your case $p(x)=x+1$ and we are done.